# disable links until css animation has completed

Tags: jquery, html, ios, css

I am using animate.css to create a hover action. On mouseenter I fadeinDown and fadeIn a text overlay to an image on a website. on mouseleave I fadeOut and fadeOutUp the text overlay.

On two of these images, there is a link. It works fine, except on mobile browsers where there is no hover. When a user clicks on the image (in say, iOS Safari) the animation effect displays the text containing the link. However, what often happens is the user clicks on the image, they also click on the link (even though it hasn't appeared yet) - which in this case sends the user to a different website.

What I'd like to have happen is (on iOS and probably other non-hover platforms) for the user to click the image with the link disabled, have the animation effect reveal the text, and then enable the link once the animation is complete.

I'm doing this right now with jQuery - all the images that are animated are class 'caption' and the ones with links are class 'FE'.

This seems to work - sort of well. Hard to explain, it seems to take care of the disabling the link but it often takes a few presses to get it to act as a link again.

```
    $(".FE").hover(
function(){
$('.caption').click (function(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    });
   $('.caption, FE').bind('webkitAnimationEnd oanimationend msAnimationEnd animationend',
function() {
   $(this).unbind('click').click()
    });
});
```

I'm not much of a JS/JQuery expert, the above is cobbled together from a few hours of googling. Hopefully someone can shed some light on the proper way to code this.

Comment: try using this: if ($(".some-animating-item").is(":amimated")) { return; } in your link click handler

Comment: I didn't know about the :animated selector - seems like it could work but I can't seem to integrate it into the code above without getting errors. The animating div would be ".caption" in my case.

Comment: this is the way to know whether any element is animated at current moment. you just use $(".some-animating-item").is(":amimated") and it return Boolean result. very easy. same way like you check checkbox input state (but with selector ":checked").

Comment: Thank, I got it to work but it turns out that my original code seems to be the best option as I really only need to know if the animation is finished.